# Push an array in the database with vanilla PHP or EspressionEngine

Tags: php, sql, arrays, database

I have an array which I've printed:

```
echo "<pre>";
print_r($obj);
die();
```

and it looks like:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Store\Model\OrderShippingMethod Object
        (
            [id] => 0
            [name] => ExpeditedParcel
            [amount] => 13.04
            [days] => 1
            [class] => CanadaPost
        )

    [1] => Store\Model\OrderShippingMethod Object
        (
            [id] => 1
            [name] => Priority
            [amount] => 25.71
            [days] => 1
            [class] => CanadaPost
        )

    [4] => Store\Model\OrderShippingMethod Object
        (
            [id] => 4
            [name] => PurolatorExpress9AM
            [amount] => 56.57
            [days] => 1
            [class] => Purolator
        )
)
```

I wish to push my array into my database but I'm not pretty sure how to do. My very first attempts generated a really weird database with a bunch of null value.. actually, all the values were null.

I used a prepared statement with ExpressionEngine, like the following:

```
ee()->db->insert(
            'exp_easypost_carriers',
            array(
                'carrier_id'    => $obj['id'],
                'carrier_name'  => $obj['name'],
                'site_id'       => 3,
                'adjustment_id' => 1,
                'rate'          => $obj['amount'],
                'days'          => $obj['days'],
            )
        );
```

But actually, I could have used a normal insert into statement with PHP in the line of:

```
$sql = "INSERT INTO exp_easypost_carriers (carrier_id, carrier_name, site_id, adjustment_id, rate, days)
VALUES ($obj['id'], $obj['name'], 3, 1, $obj['amount'], $obj['days']";
```

Still, I prefer the statement with ExpressionEngine since I'm working in that environment, which is pretty close to the vanilla PHP statement. But it doesn't work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're dealing with an array of objects, not arrays. So the way to access the data is, for instance, $obj->id. Try this statement:

```
ee()->db->insert(
        'exp_easypost_carriers',
        array(
            'carrier_id'    => $obj->id,
            'carrier_name'  => $obj->name,
            'site_id'       => 3,
            'adjustment_id' => 1,
            'rate'          => $obj->amount,
            'days'          => $obj->days
        )
);
```

Comment: Great catch.. I've just realized that.. and it actually worked!